# webpage design bootstrap 4 resizable columns

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, web-deployment

Making a website mostly focused for mobile. Trying to get the categories menu (circular photos) to be centred when on desktop browser and then resize and stack into 2 rows of 3 when in viewing on mobile. Could someone help me with the correct bootstrap4 commands to make this work?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD0aB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQst2.jpg

Comment: Can you add source code to check?

Comment: <div class="container wrapper ctop">
   <div class="row pl-5 pt-3 pb-2">
   
   <div class="col-xs-2 pl-3">
    <a class="nav-link" href='category.php?filter=Computing'><img class="rounded-circle img-nav " src="images/computing.png" alt="" /></a>
  <p class="text-center"><strong>Computing</strong></p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-2 pl-3">
    <a class="nav-link" href='category.php?filter=Televisions'><img class="rounded-circle img-nav" src="images/tv.png" alt="" /></a>
    <p class="text-center"><strong>Televisions</strong></p>
   </div>

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">One</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Two</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Three</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Four</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Five</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">One</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Two</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Three</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Four</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Five</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">Six</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks to Farhan Erooth for the answer!

Comment: Why did you copy/paste Farhan Erooth’s answer in yours?